# python $pred and $folds dont work

Tags: python, classification, knn

I'm trying to use KernelKnnCv using the HOG-descriptors to solve the cifar-10 dataset classification. I found this code snippet:

```
X, y = data, labels

hog = HOG_apply(X,cells = 6,orientations = 9,rows = 32,columns = 32,threads = 6)
fit_hog = KernelKnnCV(hog, y, k = 20, folds = 4, method = 'braycurtis',
                      weights_function = 'biweight_tricube_MULT', regression = F,
                      threads = 6, Levels = sort(unique(y)))
acc_fit_hog = unlist(lapply(1:length(fit_hog$preds),function(x) acc(y[fit_hog$folds[[x]]]
                    ,fit_hog$preds[[x]])))
```

and i get syntax error because of the $preds and $folds. how to fix it?

Comment: Posting the exact error message you get is always a good start. However, `$` is not part of Python's syntax. Are you sure it is Python?

Comment: The last line is definitely `R` code.